# PrimeNg p-table responsive with display:grid not working

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a div with containing two other div with a "display:grid" on it. Inside the second div I have a primeng p-table, like this:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 200px auto;">
  <div>sidebar</div>
  <div class="card">
    <p-table #table responsiveLayout="scroll" [value]="products">
      <ng-template pTemplate="caption"> Scroll </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Reviews</th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.price | currency: 'USD' }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.category }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
          <td>
            {{ product.inventoryStatus }}
          </td>
          <td>
            Rating
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

see working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableresponsive-demo-benuuw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

When I remove the display:grid p-table correctly shows a scrollbar for it's content if the content is too wide. However, with the display:grid the scrollbar appears on the whole page. I reported a bug but it says it will take several weeks to get a response. It works with 'display: grid; grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;' but I want the table to take all of the width available.

Does anyone know a workaround? Maybe css?

PS: this also happens with display:flex

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it cannot handle percentage as width (width:100%). A working solution is to calculate the width in the grid template, like this:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 200px calc(100% - 200px);">
```

Maybe this helps someone.